Solve system of coupled non-homogeneous difference equations
I'd like to solve the following system of coupled non-homogeneous difference equations:
\begin{align}
a x_{k-2} + b y_{k-2} + c x_{k-1} + a x_k - b y_k & =
\cos(\omega t_k)
\\[1mm]
-b x_{k-2} + a y_{k-2} + c y_{k-1} + b x_k - a y_k & = 0
\\[2mm]
\mbox{for}\quad a,b,c \in \mathbb{R},\ c > 0.&
\end{align}

Ideally, I would like to find closed-form expressions for $x_k$ and $y_k$.
Alternatively, a frequency response for $x_k$ relative to the $\it non\mbox{-}homogeneous$ input term would also be amazing.

Any help is appreciated.

What have you tried so far ? You may start by translating this system matricially for example.
